# Passing a variable into an other function ( jeasyui )

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

**Hello**, I have been desperately trying to pass a variable between functions, I have tried some solutions but they didn't worked - maybe I do it wrong. I got no ideas how to solve this, this might be trivial for some of you, looking forward a help.

**How does it work** : The input radio's are supposed to add a parameter in the url ( queryParams - all should be ok according to the documentation ), I call it a additional filter for displaying specified data. When you click a radio script gets the value and should attach it to the queryParams.

*If you have more questions don't hesitate to ask.*

```
<div class="adv_filter">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="letter_type" data-custom="Radio1" value="0">Radio1</li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="letter_type" data-custom="Radio2" value="1" checked="checked">Radio2</li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="letter_type" data-custom="Radio3" value="2">Radio3</li>
</div>

$("li").on("click", "input", function () {
    $('#dg').datagrid('reload'); //reloads the grid
    alert($(this).val()); //gets the value of input type radio
    globalVar = $(this).val(); //assign the value to a global variable
    $('#string').html(globalVar);
});

$('#dg').datagrid({

    url: 'data_loader.php',
    queryParams: { //this adds to the url ?ltype=valur
        ltype: globalVar //assign the global variable here
    }
});
//$('#string2').html(globalVar);
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rmt0r563/).

Comment: You only call `.datagrid` once. It was passed whatever value `globalVar` had at the time. It doesn't magically get re-evaluated unless *you actually call it again*

Comment: @MattBurland So is there any way to do it the other way? There is also a function $('#dg').datagrid('load', { ltype: globalVar  }); that reloads it with a parameter

Comment: @user3793639 I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The code for `#dg` is executed immediately.  It is not executed after the `click`. So `globalVar` is passed when the page loads but never again.

Comment: @user3793639: I'm not familiar with this `datagrid` control, but presumably there is a way to reload it while changing the parameters. Or you might just be able to call `.datagrid` again and replace the whole thing.

Comment: `$('#dg').datagrid('reload');`  This line is where you need to pass `globalVar`.

Comment: @MattBurland I can't add a tag for jeasyui http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php# head over to datagrid and tree -> datagrid, Well only if you want of course:)

Comment: Can you just do this: http://jsfiddle.net/rmt0r563/4/ It looks like it's firing off requests (judging form the console) as you click each radio button.

Comment: @MattBurland Please answer to the topic so I can approve the solution ;) It worked as it supposed to

Comment: @user3793639: Converted to a stack snippet and posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to just call `.datagrid` again.

```js
$("li").on("click", "input", function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#string').html(val);
    updateDataGrid(val);
});

updateDataGrid();   // this initial call may or may not be needed. 
                    // if the grid should load something on start up
                    // then pass a parameter to it here.

function updateDataGrid(query) {
    $('#dg').datagrid({

        url: 'data_loader.php',
        queryParams: { 
            ltype: query 
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<hr>Filter
<hr>
<div class="adv_filter">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="letter_type" data-custom="Radio1" value="0">Radio1</li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="letter_type" data-custom="Radio2" value="1" checked="checked">Radio2</li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="letter_type" data-custom="Radio3" value="2">Radio3</li>
</div>
<hr>
<table class="easyui-datagrid" id="dg" title="Basic DataGrid" style="width:700px;height:250px" data-options="singleSelect:true,collapsible:true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-options="field:'itemid',width:80">Item ID</th>
            <th data-options="field:'productid',width:100">Product</th>
            <th data-options="field:'listprice',width:80,align:'right'">List Price</th>
            <th data-options="field:'unitcost',width:80,align:'right'">Unit Cost</th>
            <th data-options="field:'attr1',width:250">Attribute</th>
            <th data-options="field:'status',width:60,align:'center'">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<hr>
<!-- debug -->inside
<div id="string"></div>
<hr>outer
<div id="string2"></div>
```